# C# StreamReader.Readline() in while loop giving me nullable to non nullable warning

Tags: c#, file, streamreader, nullable-reference-types

So my question is i'm getting a warning from visual studio stating that

> "null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type"

and the code works and executes as expected, however i still receive this warning and i'm unsure how to resolve the issue.

i have declared `StreamReader` as a `private` property at the start. If someone could point me into a direction or suggest an improvement to prevent this warning it would be appreciated, i have attached the relevant code below:

```
private StreamReader? streamReader;
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CreateFiles();
            ReadFiles();
        }

private void ReadFiles()
    {
        streamReader = File.OpenText(path + _productTypeFile);
        string line = "";
        if (streamReader == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occured with stream reader");
        }
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            currentProdTypeListBox.Items.Add(line);
        }
        if (streamReader.ReadLine() == null) streamReader.Close();
    }
```

The line below is where the warning is coming from:

```
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Comment: Why did you declare your streamreader at the class level?

Comment: i'm new and thought it would make sense to do it at the class level as i intend to use it in other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function to this:

```
private void ReadFiles()
{
   string path = "your path";
   using StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(path );

   if (streamReader == null)
      throw new Exception("An error occured with stream reader");
   var line = "";
   while (( line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
    currentProdTypeListBox.Items.Add(line);
   }
   streamReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have just tried that and it still giving me the same warning on the while loop

Comment: I have just tried your edit and it gives me a full error saying: string is a type which is not valid in the given context

Comment: I corrected the code

Comment: Thank you this solved it, visual studio suggested i change string? to var which would be better to use or should i ignore this suggestion?

Comment: yes ,var is better

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [nullable warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings) page of the C# language reference. `CS8600` links to the [possible null assigned to a nonnullable reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference) section which explains that the "*compiler emits these warnings when you attempt to assign an expression that is maybe-null to a variable that is nonnullable*" and details actions you can take to address these warnings.

For example, you could make the variable a nullable reference type by adding the `?` annotation, e.g.:

```
string line? = "";
```

However, this changes its default *null-state* from *not-null* to *maybe-null*, in your example this probably isn't an issue, but if the variable was used more widely the compiler's static analysis may find instances where you dereference a variable that is *maybe-null*.

Additionally, if you're going to adopt this approach, I'd urge you to use the [string.Empty field](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.empty) instead of the `""` [magic string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string), e.g.:

```
string line? = string.Empty;
```

Another approach, as [Nima Habibollahi suggested in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926732#answer-72926828) is to use `var`, e.g.:

```
var line = string.Empty;
```

Using `var` sets the default *null-state* to *maybe-null*. Using a variable explicity defined as a nullable string vs implicity definied as a string is down to individual preference [IMHO](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IMHO).

Finally, one other way of addressing the warning is by adding the null forgiving operator, `!` to the `ReadLine()` call, e.g.:

```
string line = "";
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()!) != null)
```

The other suggestion offered in the [nullable warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings) page is not relevant to your code as you cannot instruct the compiler that the right-hand-side of the assignment is *not-null* because it is `null` that you are testing for, so forcing it to be *not-null* would break your code.